# Should a constructor for a class that contains a move-only type receive the move-only type by reference or by rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I recently started learning about move semantics, and I have been thinking about the following problem for a few days:

Let's say we have a non-copyable class like the following:

```cpp
class Texture
{
public:

   Texture(unsigned int texID);
   ~Texture();

   Texture(const Texture&) = delete;
   Texture& operator=(const Texture&) = delete;

   Texture(Texture&& rhs);
   Texture& operator=(Texture&& rhs);

   // ...

private:

   unsigned int mTexID;
};
```

For those wondering, it is common to have such wrapper classes when working with OpenGL. The ID is used to access data that is stored in the GPU, and it is used to tell the GPU to destroy said data, which is done in the destructor of this wrapper class. That is why it is a non-copyable class.

Now let's say we have another non-copyable class like the following:

```cpp
class Mesh
{
public:

   // Notice how the constructor receives the vector of Texture objects (a move-only type) by reference
   Mesh(const std::vector<unsigned int>& indices, std::vector<Texture>& textures)
      : mIndices(indices)
      , mTextures(std::move(textures))
   {
      // ...
   }
   ~Mesh();

   Mesh(const Mesh&) = delete;
   Mesh& operator=(const Mesh&) = delete;

   Mesh(Mesh&& rhs);
   Mesh& operator=(Mesh&& rhs);

   // ...

private:

   std::vector<unsigned int> mIndices;
   std::vector<Texture>      mTextures;
};
```

With the constructor the way it is right now, a client could create a `Mesh` by doing the following:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
std::vector<Texture> textures;

// ...

Mesh mesh(indices, textures); // Client is unaware that the textures vector has been moved from
```

My question is whether it would be better if the constructor of the `Mesh` class was declared like this:

```cpp
// Notice how the constructor receives the vector of Texture objects (a move-only type) by rvalue reference
Mesh::Mesh(const std::vector<unsigned int>& indices, std::vector<Texture>&& textures)
   : mIndices(indices)
   , mTextures(std::move(textures))
{
   // ...
}
```

With this new constructor, the client would be forced to do the following when creating a `Mesh` object:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned int> indices;
std::vector<Texture> textures;

// ...

Mesh mesh(indices, std::move(textures)); // Client is fully aware that the textures vector has been moved from
```

It is certainly more typing, but now the user is fully aware that the textures vector has been moved from, and I don't see any performance implications.

So I guess my question is: are there are guidelines on what's the best way to receive move-only types that will be moved from? Receiving by reference to const clearly indicates that the type will not be moved from, so how does one do the opposite? How does one tell the client that the type will be moved from?

Comment: This is largely a personal choice. A non-const lvalue reference implies permission to modify the object being passed. A non-const rvalue reference implies permission to move the object being passed. The end result is the same in this case. But since the constructor in question is performing a move, an rvalue reference makes more sense to self-document what the code actually does.

Comment: @Nikos C But a vector that contains a move-only type (like Texture) is a move-only type, correct?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wish I could accept your comment as the answer to this question! You are right that this is a personal choice, and I agree that the rvalue reference makes more sense to self-document the code. Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: Note that you should declare the move-constructor and move-assignment as `noexcept` in order to make a vector of the type be usable.  (Inserting into the vector might require all objects to be moved, and this can't be done safely if the move process might throw)

Comment: I think you basically answer your own question in the question, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the rvalue reference is clearly superior if the value passed might be a prvalue:

```
struct A {};
struct B {B(A&);};
struct C {C(A&&);};
A get();
A a;

B b{a};              // OK: a is an lvalue
B b2{get()};         // error: prvalue
C c{a};              // error: lvalue
C c2{std::move(a)};  // OK: xvalue
C c3{get()};         // OK: prvalue
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of this limitation! Thanks for pointing that out.